# Looking for updated SSG for Amazon Linux 2 and Amazon Linux 2023

Tags: amazon-linux-2, openscap

Are there any new data stream and xccdf checklist available for Amazon Linux 2 and Amazon Linux 2023?

I am able to install the scap-security-guide on an Amazon Linux 2 server, but the data stream xml file and xccdf xml file are from 2019 with an extremely outdated DISA STIG RHEL7 profile.

What is the method to build a new profile based on DISA's STIG releases?

Comment: Amazon Linux 2 *is* RHEL 7 under the hood

Answer (score 0):

You can contribute in the Upstream for scap-security-guide package: https://github.com/ComplianceAsCode/content

So far, currently there is no contributors working on profiles for Amazon Linux. New contributors are welcome.